# window manager: Newly launched applications are not visible while the wm is running

Tags: linux, x11, window-managers, xcb

**TL;DR**

I'm writing a simple reparenting window manager. I'm testing it with the help of Xephyr. While the window manager is running, any application launched during that time, is not shown (not visible) on the screen, whereas any application launched before the window manager was launched is shown (visible).

**Full Question**

I'm writing a simple reparenting window manager. Currently I'm handling only two events `XCB_CREATE_NOTIFY` and `XCB_BUTTON_PRESS`. I've registered for `XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT` and `XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE` on the root window.

I'm testing the wm with Xephyr. And while testing any application launched after the wm has launched, is not shown (not visible) on the screen, while applications that have been launched before launching the wm, are shown perfectly (visible).

I read somewhere that registering for EXPOSURE event on the root window will solve the problem, but that doesn't seem the case for me. Below is my code for the CREATE_NOTIFY event, that attempts to reparent the client window and map it on screen (I think this is where I'm doing something wrong):

```
case XCB_CREATE_NOTIFY:
    {
        xcb_create_notify_event_t *cre;
        cre = (xcb_create_notify_event_t *)evt;

        xcb_window_t frame = xcb_generate_id(conn);
        uint32_t frameMask = XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
        uint32_t fM_values[2];
        fM_values[0] = custTeal->pixel; //custTeal is a custom Teal color that I've defined
        fM_values[1] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS | XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_POINTER_MOTION;

        xcb_window_t toBeMapped = cre->window;
        xcb_get_geometry_reply_t *tbm_window_geo = xcb_get_geometry_reply(conn,xcb_get_geometry(conn,toBeMapped),NULL);

        xcb_create_window(conn,0,frame,screen->root,tbm_window_geo->x,tbm_window_geo->y,(tbm_window_geo->width+4),(tbm_window_geo->height+4),1,XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,screen->root_visual,frameMask,fM_values);

        xcb_reparent_window(conn,toBeMapped,frame,2,2);

        xcb_map_window(conn,frame);
        xcb_map_window(conn,toBeMapped);

        xcb_flush(conn);
    }
    break;
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here (I'm pretty new to this). **Do I have to handle the EXPOSE event too? How do I handle it?**

**Testing**

Im launching Xephyr with

```
Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 1240x720 :2 &
```

and launching new applications with (take xterm as an example):

```
DISPLAY=:2 xterm &
```

Now, any application launched before launching the wm (or when the wm is not running) is shown perfectly in Xephyr. But after I launch the wm, any application launched is not showm.

Comment: Random suggestion: Read dwm's source code and try to understand it. Look up the parts that you do not understand. I do not really know dwm's source code, but I know that it is a window manager and that its source code is small, so I hope this is helpful in understanding how WMs work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SubstructureRedirect means that when something else tries to map a window, the X11 server instead generated a MapRequest event and sends that to the WM. Thus, you should handle `XCB_MAP_REQUEST` events. The simplest way to do that would be to `xcb_map_window` the window from the event.

Comment: After reading your whole question: Do not do what you are doing in response to `XCB_CREATE_NOTIFY`. Instead, do that in response to `XCB_MAP_REQUEST` events.

Comment: At First I handled the MAP_REQUEST event. That didn't work out, so I read an answer here on SO that talked about handling the CREATE_NOTIFY event so I changed my code, but still it didn't work.

Comment: Well, first google result for "simple xcb window manager" is https://github.com/mil/simple-wm. Perhaps this helps you (even though it uses Xlib instead of XCB). It also does nothing on CreateNotify events (calls an empty function) and only handles MapRequests. Oh and nowhere does the word "expose" appear.

Comment: Try testing the wm you mentioned (as I'm doing) and I think you would understand my question. I'm using tinywm as a reference and even it has the same problem.

Comment: I can't see what you are referring to. Here is a screenshot of urxvt running with simple-wm in Xephyr: https://imgur.com/a/HBwYWWn

Comment: Did you launch the terminal before launching the wm or after? Because whenever I run xterm before the wm is launched it is visible, but not so when o run it after the wm. I think I'll upload a GIF or a video to help you better understand my problem.

Comment: I started first simple-wm and then urxvt. If I do it the other way around, then the WM does not manage the window, which can be seen from the missing cyan border around it.

Comment: The problem is solved now. The problem was related to xterm which I was launching for testing. But other apps like xlogo, the KDE terminal and gedit worked fine after I replaced create_notify with map request.